# javascript GET and POST method not working because of Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been trying to make a simple chat app using express and sockets but 
for some reason, my GET and PUT requests are not going through. After debugging for some time i found that simply changing the bootsrap cdn did the trick but i dont understand why.

This is with the cdn given in the Bootstrap website(once you click on the submit button nothing happens)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <title>live chat</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <br>
        <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4">Send Message</h1>
        <br>
        <input id = "name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
        <br>
        <textarea id = "message" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message Here">
       </textarea>
        <br>
        <button id="send" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
        </div>
        <div id="messages">
       </div>
       </div>

    <script>
    $(() => {
    $("#send").click(()=>{
       sendMessage({
          name: $("#name").val(), 
          message:$("#message").val()});
        })
      getMessages()
    })
function addMessages(message){
   $("#messages").append(`
      <h4> ${message.name} </h4>
      <p>  ${message.message} </p>`)
   }
function getMessages(){
  $.get('http://localhost:3000/messages', (data) => {
   data.forEach(addMessages);
   })
 }
function sendMessage(message){
   $.post('http://localhost:3000/messages', message)
 }
    </script>



  </body>
</html>
```

the above codes get/put request does not work 
but if i add the following cdn instead

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

everything seems to run fine. whats the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Slim removes several features. The reason your code works in the second example is because you are using the full version of jQuery.